# Keeping images bound to their DIV

Tags: html, css, overflow

I put images inside a DIV. I want all three pictures to be inside their DIV border, but it just doesn't seem to work:

```css
#container {
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#original,
#alike1,
#alike2 {
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 255);
}

img.pic2,
img.pic3 {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

#pic1 {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <h1> Trump Hair </h1>

  <div id="original">
    <h2> Original </h2>
    <p> The Donald
      <div> <img id=pic1 height="100" alt="Don" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people"> </div>
    </p>
    <p> This is the original Trump hair. It is found often in nature.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div id="alike1">
    <h2> Look alike #1</h2>
    <p>Corn Silk <img class="pic2" height="100" alt="Corn" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats"></p>
    <p>There have been many cases of corn silk that appear like Trump's hair.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div id="alike2">
    <h2> Look alike #1 </h2>
    <p> Llama Hair <img class="pic3" alt="llama" height="100" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract"> </p>
    <p> There are many animals that have Trump hair. This llama is looking very stylish. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I fix it? I want all three pictures to be inside their DIV border, but now it looks like this:

[as you can see the images flow out of the divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfMCb.png):

[image: 1]

Comment: Please go read [ask], and also how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Bob.C what do you mean please can you let me know how are you expecting your output to be ?

Comment: I want all three pictures to be inside their DIV border. If you haven't please take a look at the picture linked in "as you can see the images...."

Comment: Looks like your code snippet works, so we're missing some html or css that is changing the outcome. Show everything if you can, or create a fiddle we can look at.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xoa5htvp/

Comment: There are html errors - divs inside p's - and other things. start by cleaning it up. copy from here - https://jsfiddle.net/bbcjvsx3/ - you can also use the 'Tidy' button on the menu (for css). see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the images are floating. When you float an element, it is taken out of the normal flow of the page (as when you do a position absolute or fixed).

One possible solution would be to make the box grow to fit the image within it. You can achieve that by adding `overflow:auto` and `height:auto`, then the box will grow to include all the floating elements within its limits:

```css
#container {
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#original,
#alike1,
#alike2 {
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 255);
  /* add the changes here */
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

img.pic2,
img.pic3 {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

#pic1 {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <h1> Trump Hair </h1>

  <div id="original">
    <h2> Original </h2>
    <p> The Donald
      <div> <img id=pic1 height="100" alt="Don" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people"> </div>
    </p>
    <p> This is the original Trump hair. It is found often in nature.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div id="alike1">
    <h2> Look alike #1</h2>
    <p>Corn Silk <img class="pic2" height="100" alt="Corn" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats"></p>
    <p>There have been many cases of corn silk that appear like Trump's hair.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div id="alike2">
    <h2> Look alike #1 </h2>
    <p> Llama Hair <img class="pic3" alt="llama" height="100" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract"> </p>
    <p> There are many animals that have Trump hair. This llama is looking very stylish. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```